# How can I set the memory size for Intern when run from Grunt?

Tags: intern

Presumably to increase Intern's memory limit you would do something like:

```
npx --max-old-space-size=8192 intern
```

But how do I do it when running Intern from Grunt?  For Intern 3, it looks like node_modules/intern/tasks/intern.js spawns Intern as a separate process from Grunt, so the option should be passed there.  But for Intern4 it's less clear to me.  Maybe Intern is run in the Grunt process, in which case I would need to increase the memory limit for Grunt itself?

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that Intern is run in the grunt process, so increasing grunt's memory allocation is the way to go.